# How to get today's day and transform it to a string using vala / genie?

Tags: string, date, glib, vala, genie

I have this code, but it fails. Why?

```
// tomar la fecha
fecha = GLib.Date();
print "cogiendo"
var s = new StringBuilder("Fecha:");
dia:DateDay= fecha.get_day();
s.append_printf ("%u",dia);
print s.str;
fecha_str=s.str;
```

Glib returns: 
 g_date_get_day: assertion 'g_date_valid (d)' failed

Comment: Sorry, I want to take the current date, today's date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [`GLib.DateTime` class](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.DateTime) for this purpose.

You didn't write if you want the current date as a locale dependent or independent format.

Locale dependent, using [`format ()`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.DateTime.format):

```cs
var dt = new DateTime.now_local ();
stdout.puts (dt.format ("%x"));
```

Locale independent, using [`to_string ()`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.DateTime.to_string) (beware that this will also include the time):

```cs
var dt = new DateTime.now_local ();
stdout.puts (@"$dt");
```

In a custom format using [`format ()`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.DateTime.format):

```cs
var dt = new DateTime.now_local ();
stdout.puts (dt.format ("%d/%m/%Y")); // 29/09/2014
```

I took the custom format from your own answer, but I wouldn't use it as it's confusing, because usually with `/` delimited dates have the format `"%m/%d/%Y"` or `"%m/%d/%y"`.

I would prefer either the locale default format (which is what the user expects) or the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format which you get with `to_string ()` or without the time with `format ("%F")`.

Comment: With glib 2.58 I now get dt assert != null messages if I go through a foreach loop. Why is that? Should I add assert( dt != null) before stdout ?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> If the Date-struct is obtained from `g_date_new`, it will be safe to mutate but invalid and thus not safe for calendrical computations.

Perhaps you want to `set_time_t`, or `set_time_val`. If you want today's date, `fecha.set_time_t(time_t());`

Answer (score 0):

This code goes well!! Searched in gnome's vala samples:

```
var now = new DateTime.now_local ();
fecha_str = now.get_day_of_month ().to_string()+"/"+now.get_month ().to_string()+"/"+now.get_year ().to_string()
```